# DjangoRestFramework HTML views timeout

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, connection-timeout

I have created an application that uses django-rest-framework. The problem is that in production with lots of data, the rendering of HTML pages will timeout. This is caused, I believe, by the `select` fields that represent `ForeignKey` of the model that take too long to render when all the production data is available. What is the most approriate way to prevent this?

Comment: Could you show us that form, the template and the view that is timing out?

Comment: The form is autogenerated byt djangorestframework. It is not a custom view.

Comment: The form contains some foreign keys, right?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the unprecise question. Edited it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, the problem is with the selectbox loaded with tons of items. The solution that is being used in django admins is to use "raw_id_fields" for the choicefields (or foreign keys) that have lots of items.

Unfortunately, DRF doesn't support Raw ID fields for now. However, you can implement a similar approach by using autocomplete fields. Right now there isn't built-in support, but you can use some external packages as described in DRF's official documentation: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api/#autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

You should use `select_related()`/`prefetch_related` queryset methods to fetch the associated objects, which fill your selects. Post your models, serializer and a queryset so we can make a real example.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and it's not a problem with database queries because the JSON version renders very quickly